# Syntax error on a doctrine query (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Im getting a syntax error on this query:

```
protected function _getimsg($id)
{
    $imsgRepository = $this->getDoctrine( )->getRepository( 'DonePunctisBundle:Imsg' );
    $imsg = $imsgRepository->findOneBy(array('to' => $id, 'read' => 0 ));
    if($imsg) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $imsg->setRead('1');

        $em->persist( $imsg );
        $em->flush( );

        return $imsg->getContent();
    } else {
        return '';
    }

}
```

### imsg Entity

```
<?php

namespace Done\PunctisBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Imsg
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="imsg")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Imsg
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="to", type="string", length=25)
 */
private $to;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="read", type="integer", length=1)
 */
private $read;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set To
 *
 * @param string $to
 * @return Page
 */
public function setTo($to)
{
    $this->to = $to;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get to
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTo()
{
    return $this->to;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return Page
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set read
 *
 * @param integer $read
 * @return Imsg
 */
public function setRead($read)
{
    $this->read = $read;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get read
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getRead()
{
    return $this->read;
}

}
```

### The error output

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE imsg SET read = ? WHERE
>   id = ?' with params {"1":"1","2":1}:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = '1'
>   WHERE id = 1' at line 1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - `READ` is a reserved word. I'm guessing that's why you're getting the syntax error.

Doctrine can automatically quote the column names for you:

```
<?php
/** @Column(name="`number`", type="integer") */
private $number;
```

Add backticks to the colum's name - taken from http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the exact same issue with the exact same keyword ("read"), and was on my way to pull my entire app apart before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you use yaml, you can do this

```
Number:
type: entity
table: `number `
```